# How many applications should you provide to cover all sort of mobile phones

Tags: applications, mobile

At the moment we have:

- Iphone
- Android
- J2me touch
- J2me non-touch
- J2me touch for Blackberry
- J2me non-touch for Blackberry

We were thinking of making another

- J2me non-touch for crappy devices (because the regular non-touch is just to heavy)

The question is, can you think of any other versions of our application that we should provide to target 'ALL' mobile phones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Windows Mobile 6.5
- Windows Phone 7
- Native Symbian? But maybe the J2ME version
  is enough for that platform.

Answer (score 3):

Symbian. Nokia still has the biggest market share worldwide for all mobile phones

Answer (score 1):

***Symbian / Android / IPhone***

That's it ... this gives you a very (very!!) large majority coverage. Disregard the rest ... you cannot please everybody, and it will probably be not worth the cost either (always think of the cost/benefits).

Comment: Given the low cost of entry & development, I would say it's worth including Windows Phone 7 as a 'required' platform. Granted - it isn't right now, but it has the potential to change quickly, and the apps are (relatively) quick to develop.

Comment: @Tom Morgan - Thus maybe true, but I don't like predicting the future. For now, WP7 has neglieable market share.

Comment: I would add BlackBerry/RIM to the list above. "In the US however, Blackberry owned by RIM has over 35% in market share, while the Apple iPhone has about 28% and Google’s Android platform captures only 9% of the market."  ( http://mail2web.com/blog/2010/08/androidiphoneblackberry-market-share/ )

Comment: @tcrosley - Yeah, ok I guess. I was guessing based on what I see in my country, and in Europe where I live, BB's are relatively rare. Very rare even. Not sure why really, but that's how it is ...

Comment: @Rook, in the US, Symbian is relatively rare.  I know over there, it is a big player.  Several years ago I did some Symbian programming in London, and I thought it was going to be the next big thing in the US, but it never really took off.

Comment: @tcrosley - Oh, I didn't know that. Interesting! Must be a geographical thing. That, and US market being enough big on its own ... so that also has some influence on the distribution.